# Unity: Bone transform positions inconsistent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I'm trying to do is attach clothing to an avatar by setting the transforms of each bone in an article of clothing to be the same as the corresponding bone in the human model.
However upon experimentation, I've noticed that the position of the bone given by

```
bone.transform.position;
```

is not the same as the actual position in the scene.

For instance, upon running my code on the "Head" bone, the aforementioned code yields position (1.6, 18, -.04) but when I enter the scene and inspect the bone, its position is (-0.7700785,1.117587e-07,-2.235174e-08). Which, as you might imagine, severely messes up the process.

Below is the relevant method:

```
//copies the bone transforms from the model to the desired article of clothing
private void CopyBones (GameObject art)
{

    //for each bone in the model, modify the corresponding bone in the article
    foreach (string path in bonePaths)
    {

        Transform fromBone = art.transform.Find("Armature/" + path);
        Transform toBone = model.transform.Find("Armature/" + path);

        if (fromBone == null || toBone == null)
            Debug.Log("Could not locate: " + path);

        else
        {

            //doing this doesn't work for some reason
            //fromBone.SetPositionAndRotation(toBone.transform.position, toBone.transform.rotation);

            fromBone.transform.position = toBone.transform.position;
            fromBone.transform.rotation = toBone.transform.rotation;

            //doing this doesn't work either
            //fromBone.SetParent(toBone);
            //fromBone.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            //fromBone.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This question may be outdated, but it's the only one i found that relates to my own problem. also looking for an explanation about this...